# Django: STATIC_URL adds appname to the url

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have configured my static settings like so:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('js', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js')),
    ('css', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'css')),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

and these in my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/?$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/?$', logout_then_login, name='logout'),

    url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)$', 'profiles.views.detail'),
    url(r'^profile/edit$', 'profiles.views.edit'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

It works very well for the url `localhost:8000/login`, but when I get to the `localhost:8000/profile/edit` site, which is handled by my `profiles` App, the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` changes all the paths from `/static/...` to `/profile/static/...`, so my javascripts and stylesheets are not found any more.

What'd I do wrong?

**EDIT**: Here would be my `base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Neighr{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {% block script %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `staticfiles_urlpatterns()`? What is it?

Comment: @ Thibault J: According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development), an addition necessary to serve static files in development environment.

Comment: As stated in the link you gave, this is only valid if you don't use the django built-in server. Otherwise, static files will be served automaticaly. Which server are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example of a place you have {{ STATIC_URL }} on a profile template?

Comment: @Thibault J: Yes, I merely use the `manage.py runserver` during development. @Jordan: Edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the django built-in developement server, try to remove the following line from your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In production, you'de better not serve static files with django, so use the `collectstatic` command.

**edit**

If `settings.py`, try something like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: That still adds the `/profile` to the static path, so not solving my problem.

Comment: What is the value of `SITE_ROOT`?

Comment: ... that one is not in my `settings.py`, should I set it?

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` should be the absolute path to your static directory on the server. Try something like this: (editet my answer)