# django adding static path to current url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I have my static files in a folder `assets` in the application directory. When I go to the main page (`/`), the static files are being loaded perfectly fine from `/assets/`. If I go to `/house/`, it tries to load the static files from `/house/assets/`, which obviously results in the files not loading as they are not there.

This is the possibly relevant piece of `settings.py`:

```
...
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/assets/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
...
```

I am loading the static files in the templates using something like this:

```
<link href="assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This is the urls file for that part of the application:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^house/$', views.house, name='house'),
)
```

and these are the views:

```
def dashboard(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def house(request):
    return render_to_response('house.html')
```

I have been looking for a solution to this for the past hour with no success. I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307549/django-static-url-adds-appname-to-the-url) asking a similar thing but it did not help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the HTML tag in your template from

```
<link href="assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

to

```
<link href="/assets/plugins/uniform/css/uniform.default.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Please note the slash `/` in front of the relative URL. Without it, the browser will assume that `assets` directory is a subdirectory of the current one. With it, it will always start from the root directory.